# SQL AlwaysOn Availability Groups network performance

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, network

Our customers are asking to implement our products while configuring AlwaysOn Availability Groups (  between two FCI with Asynchronic  commit ). The DR server is geographically far from the Production server ( e.g . > 300 km ) . 
Each customer may use different parts of the product running with different functionality and different load (e.g. different number of concurrent users). 
Network latency is obviously one of the factors that will affect RTO and sync functionality with AlwaysOn Availability Groups.
My question is what will be considered a good / bad network response ? Are there any general network guidelines or counters thresholds relevant for Availability Groups?
Will 50 ms round trip be a reasonable threshold as a general guideline?
What else should I take into account regarding network performance when using AlwaysOn Availability Groups?